# multiple lines of syntax inside lapply

Tags: r, lapply

How do I specify multiple lines of syntax inside a lapply. My syntax is also not substituting the text_query in the first line. Thank you in advance.

```
text_query<-lapply(text_query, function(x) {   gsub("ABC", "ABD", x, fixed=TRUE)   gsub("JKL", "JKM", x, fixed=TRUE) } )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jean, `lapply` is accepting your second argument as a `lambda`, or anonymous / unnamed, function.

Both examples use `text_query <- "ABC JKL"` as example data and return `list('ABD JKM')` as their result.

Version one:

```
text_query <- lapply(text_query, function(x) {
  x <- gsub("ABC", "ABD", x, fixed=TRUE)
  gsub("JKL", "JKM", x, fixed=TRUE)
})

text_query
```

Version two, replacing your `lambda` with a named function `mySub`:

```
mySub <- function(string) {
  string <- gsub("ABC", "ABD", x, fixed=TRUE)
  gsub("JKL", "JKM", string, fixed=TRUE)
}

text_query <- lapply(text_query, mySub)

text_query
```

Note, both assume you want both `gsub` calls applied to your supplied argument.

Answer (score 5):

*R* does not care about new lines within one operation, so you can just write:

```
text_query <- lapply(text_query, function(x) {
    gsub("ABC", "ABD", x, fixed=TRUE)
    gsub("JKL", "JKM", x, fixed=TRUE)
})
```

Or, if you want it in one line, you can separate statements with a semicolon, i.e.

```
text_query<-lapply(text_query, function(x) {   gsub("ABC", "ABD", x, fixed=TRUE); gsub("JKL", "JKM", x, fixed=TRUE) } )
```

I think the first option is a lot more understadable, though ^^

Comment: I'll let you have this one ;)